# Fallout 4 Neon Flats (Creation Club Content) Top Floor Bugged

Tags: fallout-4

Upon entering the Top floor of Neon Flats, one of the creation club apartments located in Goodneighbor, the issue occurs as soon as the 2nd elevator's doors open: I begin falling through the ground. Eventually I am below all of Goodneighbor, and of course I am soft locked down there, unable to escape.

I can still access the middle floor, but the top floor currently remains inaccessible. How can I fix this? I'm concerned this is permanent and I wanted to build a nightclub up there.

Edit: Not sure if version matters, but I'm on Steam/PC.

Comment: When i have clipping issues in Bethesda games, it's often tied to fps throwing off the physics engine. How's your FPS?

Comment: Hmm I don't have many frames issues unless I'm streaming, and even then it's only once in awhile it seems, but I'll try to enter floor 2 while not streaming and see what happens...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon entering the top floor of Neon Flats and the falling begins use the below console command:

> coc GoodneighborTheMemoryDen

This teleports the player to the interior of The Memory Den just outside Neon Flats... which fixes the issue, somehow.

If you are in survival without access to console you can temporarily leave survival, do the teleport, then use the following command to enable switching back to survival (you still need to menu and switch to survival after the command):

> cgf "Game.IncrementStat" "Survival Denied" -1

Comment: Thanks to a viewer who just told me the solution one day... and fosst on steam forums for the survival reenabling.

Comment: Also I realized, this may not help console (Xbox/PS) players, as I don't remember having access to console commands on my Xbox. :(